scrolling snapping to next item instead of moving continuously
I have a navigation menu with overflow-y: scroll property, this navigation menu consists of multiple items.
I want to know if there is a way that each time user moves the scrollbar, it moves exactly to next item of menu.
this is my menu

and once the user moves the scroll bar I want the navigation menu to snap to second item like this:


Please post a [mcve]

Scroll-snap-type: both mandatory;
Scroll-behaviour: smooth;
